# Python: How to draw some boxplots for data frames using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe with 4 columns - `id`, `label`, `var1` and `var2`.

From this data, I would like to draw two box plots each for `var1` and `var2` - one for where the `label==0` and the other for where `label==1`.

Sample dataframe:

```
+-----+-----+----+----+
| id  |label|var1|var2|
+-----+-----+----+----+
| 1   |  0  | 0.7| 0.6|
| 2   |  0  | 0.3| 0.4|
| 3   |  1  | 0.2| 0.2|
| 4   |  1  | 0.8| 0.1|
| 5   |  0  | 0.0| 0.9|
+-----+-----+----+----+
```

Code to generate dataframe:

```
l=[(1,0,0.7,0.6),(2,0,0.3,0.4),(3,1,0.2,0.2),(4,1,0.8,0.1),(5,0,0.0,0.9)]
names=["id","label", "var1", "var2"]
db=sqlContext.createDataFrame(l,names)
db.show()
db = db.toPandas()
```

How can I implement this using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `df.boxplot()` on your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l=[(1,0,0.7,0.6),(2,0,0.3,0.4),(3,1,0.2,0.2),(4,1,0.8,0.1),(5,0,0.0,0.9)]
names=["id","label", "var1", "var2"]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=names)

df.boxplot(column=["var1", "var2"],by="label")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I set y-axis limit in matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, [set y-axis limit in matplotlib](http://www.google.de/search?q=set+y-axis+limit+in+matplotlib).